# POSTing image to a PHP web service from WPF (C# / VB .Net)

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, http-post, webclient

I have a form in **WPF** which opens the File Dialog box and one can select an image. When the **"Save"** button on the form is clicked, ideally the image should get saved to a folder on my web server. I found no direct way to upload a file to a FTP folder on my server, so I employed a PHP web service to do that for me.

So I want to send the image using POST method to `uploadImage.php` web service which checks for image and then save it in the folder on my server. Thanks for any help.

My current try *(in VB.Net although even C# example would suffice)*:

```
  Dim client = New WebClient()
  client.UploadFile("http://www.foo.com/imageUpload.php",doctorPic.Source.ToString())
  //doctorPic is the name of the image control in WPF
```

Comment: You have to pass the image file path (from the FileDialog) to `UploadFile`, not Source.ToString.

Comment: I have never used WCF or any WebServices practically. But I watch videos on www.youtube.com/kudvenkat regularly, where You may get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you created a BitmapImage from the file path returned from a FileDialog, you may recover that path from the Image control like this:

```
var bitmap = (BitmapImage)doctorPic.Source;
var uri = bitmap.UriSource;
var path = uri.AbsolutePath;
client.UploadFile("http://www.foo.com/imageUpload.php", path);
```

Otherwise you could simply store the file path somewhere (e.g. in a local variable or a field in your class) and use that in UploadFile.

Comment: This does pass on the image to the URL, but it does not POST it as I check for $_POST['file'] on my PHP web service.

Comment: Did you try it? Please read the [UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx) documentation again, especially the Remarks section.